# Suggested edit marked approved when rolled back

Tags: discussion, review-queues, revision-history

Whilst doing some reviewing I came across [**this edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5587391) that I was about to reject. When I clicked to reject, I got the "This has already been approved" dialog, and wanted to undo it as it was clearly an invalid edit.

This was correct as it turned out that the editor had edited the wrong answer (instead of their own answer) by mistake and then rolled back the edit.

The action of rolling back an edit in the review queue currently displays as **Community approved**:

[image]

Is this behavior just a catch all for edits that no longer need action, or should there be a more descriptive message displayed in both the dialog and the review history?

The dialog could simply read something along the lines of:

> No action required, this edit has been rolled back.

I'm also wondering if there are similar cases if a post is deleted whilst it's in the review queue? Does a similar dialog appear then or is it more specific? It's obviously difficult to test that.

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug or feature request, probably the latter, or more it's just by-design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Community♦ approves or rejects a suggested edit and the following review is an Edit, it just means that user improved upon the suggested edit and either marked it as helpful or unhelpful.

In this case, they found it helpful, then revised

> ( you didn't say you needed IE* support )

to

> A width for a div bordering all the images will force the boxes to move vertically to inhabit the width provided, so it'll drop down.

The rollback doesn’t affect this.

Related suggestions on Meta Stack Exchange:

- [Reviewer stats in suggested edits should show improver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179362/reviewer-stats-in-suggested-edits-should-show-improver)
- [Reject an already-approved suggested edit when rolling it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back)

Comment: I think there's an issue with those edits, as I'm 95% sure edit 3 wasn't there when I looked at the revisions yesterday, I just saw 1, 2 and the rollback, hence my question. With edit 3, the rollback makes less sense as the OP edited the post in 3, which was later deleted with the rollback, which took it to it's original state.

Comment: @Tanner: Well, it’s just not possible for you to have seen 1, 2, and the rollback. As far as post history goes, actual revisions beyond the top one can’t change.

Comment: Not possible?! You're 100% sure of that? I'm pretty sure i would have spotted that edit if it had been there. Also, if it was being rolled back, the user would have hopefully spotted that the OP had edited it since the first edit. I don't want to get hung up on this, I was just pretty sure something was awry with this.

Comment: @Tanner: Was the rollback still a suggested edit at that point, maybe?

Comment: When I clicked through to the question from the suggested edit queue, the question was in it's original format as it had already been rolled back